# What does that mean for "callfuncN_selector" in Cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, visual-studio-express

I want to run my first project in visual studio but as you see it appears to have two errors, which I have no idea what do they mean

```
void CCloud::Start(){

    this->stopAllActions();

    float currentX = this->getPositionX();
    float distance = currentX - -(_xOffset);
    float time = distance / _pixelsPerSec;
    CCPoint destination = ccp(-_xOffset, this->getPositionY());

    CCMoveTo *actionMove = CCMoveTo::create(time, destination);
    CCCallFuncN *actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN::create(this, callfuncN_selector(CCloud::ReachedDestionation));

    this->runAction(CCSequence::create(actionMove, actionMoveDone, NULL));

}
```

And the two errors are:

Error   1   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall CCloud::* )(void)' to 'cocos2d::SEL_CallFuncN'

C:\Users\sergi_000\Downloads\cocos2d-x-2.2.3\projects\myfirstapp\Classes\CCloud.cpp 27  1   HelloCpp

Error   2   error C2665: 'cocos2d::CCCallFuncN::create' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

C:\Users\sergi_000\Downloads\cocos2d-x-2.2.3\projects\myfirstapp\Classes\CCloud.cpp 27  1   HelloCpp

I would be very pleased if someone could help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to a member function is not the same as a pointer to a non-member function. A pointer to a member function needs an instance to be called on.

The usual solution to this is that the library that have callbacks allows one to set some kind of "user data", which you can then set to the object instance. Then create a callback *wrapper* function, usually as a `static` member function (which can be used as a normal non-member function pointer), and in that get the user data, cast it to the correct class, and call the function you really want to call.

Caveat: I don't know if cocos2d-x supports user-data for callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i concern, `#define callfuncN_selector(_SELECTOR) CC_CALLFUNCN_SELECTOR(_SELECTOR)` is deprecated. You should not use it.

Also CCloud::ReachedDestionation requires a function which took a CCNode* (which is also deprecated) as input. Check whether or not it is true in your example or post source code here, so I can get better answer.

Last (but not least) - its generally good practice try not to use deprecated methods, since its usually means, that engine has better opportunity.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the following code:

[image]